# Modifying SDP constraints for WebRTC in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, sdp

I am trying to reduce the bitrate in a `RTCPeerConnection` within FireFox. I have successfully been able to do within Chrome.

I am modifying the SDP string that is automatically generated by FireFox after calling the `createOffer` method. My callback modifies the SDP and then tries to set the SDP in the `RTCSessionDescription` that is generated(which is just a `DOMString` according to the protocol spec). In Chrome, I can modify that SDP string and then set it(done within a callback passed to `createOffer`:

```
desc.sdp = TransFormSDP(desc.sdp);
connection.setLocalDescription(desc);
```

However, this does not seem to be working in FireFox, it will not update the SDP after my assignment and continues to utilize the string that was generated by the `createOffer` method.

Specifically, I am trying to specifically add an `fmtp: max-fr=15; max-fs=400;` restriction on the `VP8` codec being offered and the bandwidth by adding `b=AS:512` line in the video media portion of the SDP.

Does FF not allow you to modify the SDP after it has been automatically generated? Or Does FireFox disallow specific SDP options that are part of SDP's standardization(like bandwidth limits and codec settings)?

EDIT: [Seriously FireFox??](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that for now [it is not supported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976521), at least I am assuming so because there is yet to be a response to this bug. Guess I am stuck using Chrome for now.

Comment: If somebody has a better answer, please supply one. I will accept my fate of not using FF in two days when I can accept my own answer... :(

Comment: As far as I know, it is still a bug and Mozilla has not addressed it.

Comment: It seems as of 2016 Jan, this is not (yet) supported by Firefox 48: [ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.media/Rhf3W7j1F00)

Comment: Firefox developers do not seem to be interested at all in making webRTC working according to specs. Still, it is not possible to change the bandwidth in the SDP. Audio will stay at 40 kBit/s no matter what you do. It really is a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the bitrate of the codec encoding is available throught the API, however it doesn't work very well on Firefox.

The proper API should be the one described in the specs https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcrtpencodingparameters

`RTCRtpSender.setParameters` is supported in Firefox from version 64. But actually (v.66) does not support it correctly, bitrate works, but fps doesn't.

The API way snippet to modify the bitrate:

```
const sender = peerConnection.getSenders().filter(s => s.track.kind === 'video')[0];
sender.setParameters({...(sender.getParameters()), encodings: [{
    maxBitrate: 1000*50,
}]});
```

However, chaging the bitrate throught the API has only a temporary effect in FF, as presented on the diagram below. The bitrate goes back to the default one after few seconds. The reason is not clear, probably it might be connected with the `degradationPreference` codec property since it acts differently for `balanced`, `maintain-framerate` and `maintain-resolution`. On chrome,​ it works normally.

[image]

Comment: that does not correspond with the behaviour on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/ -- if you see such behaviour please file a bug against firefox.